# Python Script within ArcMap running GME Command passes a double forward slash when writing the log file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.1, gme

I thought I made some serious headway there today. My script works perfectly fine when run from a Python Shell, but in ArcMap, whether the script is run from the Python Command line, or within a toolbox, GME fails/produces an error when loading. Another person is experiencing the [identical behavior and has a thread started on the ESRI Forums](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/91908-Python-GME-%28Spatial-Ecology%29-Subprocess.call).

Here is a screenshot of his error, my OS seems to cut off more of the error:

[image]

Has anyone else experienced this error? Are you able to execute GME commands from within an ArcMap session? There is only one config file which, while related to logging, I don't believe has any bearing on this. I'm not aware of any other switch when you execute GME from a command line which disables logging.

Comment: What version of ArcGIS are you using?  I have had some issues running GME with 10.2 installed.

Comment: AGS 10.1.1 (I downgraded from 10.2 due to license manager issues, but that's a whole other story). GME 0.7.2.1, R 64bit 3.0.1. I have an email out to Hawthorne, but haven't heard anything yet.